# MVC: Should logic be placed in the Model or Service layer?

Tags: model-view-controller

Recently I talked with a co-worker and had a conversation regarding Model View Controller paradigm. We were talking about proper organization of files and such and I mentioned that I thought that "skinny controllers and fat models" were the way to go. Meaning that the controller just calls the "fat models" methods which contain business logic:

```
public class CreditCard {
    //instance vars
    //constructor
    //getters
    //setters (if you want mutability)

    public boolean makeCreditCardPayment(Cart cart) {
    //implementation details...
    }   
}
```

My co-worker mentioned otherwise. He said that the models shouldn't really be "fat" and contain any other business logic. The model should just be a data-structure and contain zero methods (obviously if your are in Java you need setters and getters). Just like a C-style structure, obviously with data fields that have mutators and accessors:

```
public class CreditCard {
    //instance vars
    //constructor
    //getters
    //setters (if you want mutability)
}


public class PaymentService {
    public boolean makeCreditCardPayment(CreditCard card, Cart cart) {
    //implementation details...
    }   

    public boolean makePayPalPayment(PayPal paypal, Cart cart){
    //implementation details...
    }
```

Or even have a PaymentService for each type of payment that implements an interface. So something like 'CreditCardPaymentService implements Payment' or 'PayPalPaymentService implmeents Payment'.

To me, using the service method way seems like we are just going back to procedural style programming.

Another example would be a 'Vehicle' object with a getSpeed method compared to a service which takes in a Vehicle object and returns the speed.

I have looked over other stackoverflow answers but they have differing answers. In one question, one of the users mentioned that the service layer is part of the models part of MVC. I am looking for other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered many different philosophies claimed to fall under the MVC umbrella.

My position:

**Models** directly manage some kind of backing store, and should contain mutation and validation logic.

**Controllers** should look like a model to other controllers and views (making them composable), and contain any additional logic required to validate the mapping from the controller's interface to a model's interface.

**Views** just contain whatever state and logic they need to function; their purpose is to display data and collect input.

It looks like your `PaymentService` is trying to be more than one controller, so I'd go the separate `CreditCardPaymentService` and `PayPalPaymentService` route.